# jQueryの処理後に追加したものをドロップしたい

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
実現したいこと
予定リストにある要素を日付へドラッグアンドドロップできるようにしようとしています。
ドラッグアンドドロップの部分はjQuery、動的要素の作成はjavascriptを使用して作成しています。
また、図にあるMy Event１から５までの要素はHTMLで事前に作成してあるものです。

困っていること
事前に作成してある要素（My Event1から5）はドラッグアンドドロップができるのですが、動的作成した要素はドラッグはできて日付へ近づけると反応はするのですが、ドロップができません。
作成された要素がjQueryの処理が終わった後に追加されたもののためドラッグアンドドロップができないのかなという見解なのですが、改善方法がわからず困っています。

```js
//↓リストの追加
function bar() {
    // 要素の作成と属性の指定
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var newTxt = document.createTextNode( document.getElementById("favtext").value );
    newDiv.appendChild( newTxt );
 newDiv.className = "fc-event";
   

    // リストに追加
    var list = document.getElementById("external-events");
 let refNode = document.getElementById("favtext");
 list.insertBefore( newDiv, refNode );

 // 追加した要素を ドラッグ可能にする
    $(newDiv).draggable({
             zIndex: 999,
             revert: true,      // イベントをもとの状態に戻します
             revertDuration: 0  // ドラッグ後の元の位置
    });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>


 // ページ読み込み時の処理
$(document).ready(function () {

    // 外部イベントを初期化します
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------
    $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {
        // カレンダーがドロップ時にイベントをレンダリングできるようにデータを保存します
        $(this).data('event', {
            title: $.trim($(this).text()), // イベントタイトルとして要素のテキストを使用
            stick: true //ユーザがナビゲートする時に維持する(renderEventメソッドのドキュメントを参照)
        });

        // jQuery UIを使用してイベントをドラッグ可能にします
        $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true,      // イベントをもとの状態に戻します
            revertDuration: 0  // ドラッグ後の元の位置
        });
    });


    // カレンダーの設定
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        height: 550,
   firstDay: 1,
        lang: "ja",
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end) {
            var title = prompt("予定タイトル:");
            var eventData;
            if (title) {
                eventData = {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end
                };
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
            }
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
        droppable: true, // これにより、モノをカレンダーにドロップできます
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, 
    });


});

 $(".fc-unselectable").droppable({
  tolerance: 'fit',
 });



</script>

<div id='external-events'>
  <p>
    <strong>予定リスト</strong>
  </p>
  <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
  <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
  <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
  <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
  <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
 <input type="text" id="favtext" style="display:none;">
 <input type="button" id="addurl" value="追加" onclick="bar();" style="display:none;">
 <label>
  <img src="プラスオレンジ.png">
  <input type="checkbox" style="display: none;" onchange="clickBtn1(this.checked)">
 </label>
</div>
```

Comment: 質問内容が [前回](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/62472/3060) とほぼ同じに見えます。コードの一部は回答を受けて変更されているようですが、回答も踏まえた上で前回の質問とはどこが違うのかを説明した方が良いのかなと思います。

Comment: https://qa.atmarkit.co.jp/q/12611 https://teratail.com/questions/236798

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ver 3.9 と ver 4.0 では 動作がかなり違っていました。

ver 3.9 では

サンプルの中で "My Event 1" という 外部のイベントのバー には 下記２つの 設定がされています。

```
      // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
      $(this).data('event', {
        title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
        stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
      });

      // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
      $(this).draggable({
        zIndex: 999,
        revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
        revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
      });
```

下の方は ドラッグ＆ドロップを可能にする設定で 上の方は ドロップした時に Grid の中に
イベントの文字列の書かれた スティックを追加する処理のようです。

見た目は ドラッグ＆ドロップしているように見えますが、実は ドロップした瞬間に そのDIV は消えて
別の div が カレンダーの中に 書き込まれているようです。

なので ドロップした後で、カレンダーの中に文字を表示するためには 下記のコードを追加してください。

```
    $(newDiv).data('event', {
        title: $.trim($(newDiv).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
        stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
      });
```

ドキュメントには あまりちゃんと書いてなかったな・・。
ver 4.0 では ちゃんとドロップできたので 気づきませんでした・・。

[renderEvent](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/renderEvent) の部分のドキュメントみて あーそういう意味か・・ と分かりました。